# Ubuntu 18.04 snort protection

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, security, snort

Recently I installed `Snort` on my `Ubuntu server 18.04` And also wrote some rules in `local.rules` . it will perfectly detect my rules like ping , simple dos attacks etc.

I have 4 questions :

1. How can i block specific ip address , in Snort Detection rules ? (for example in dos detection rules)
2. Does Snort store any data about detection like IPs, contents etc. in some database ? with `apt-get install snort` , `mysql` has been installed to .
3. Is it possible to run a script on `alert` ?
4. When i used `reject` action and start snort in `console` mode , I got

> connection refused

error on ssh , and cant login to ssh anymore until restart the server . The rule is :

`reject tcp any any -> $HOME_NET any (msg:"simple dos attack"; threshold:type both, count 50 , seconds 5 , track by_dst ; sid:1000001 )`

Answer (score 0):

The typical way to do this is run Snort in [Inline mode](http://sublimerobots.com/2016/02/snort-ips-inline-mode-on-ubuntu/) and then modify the snort rules as shown under "Dropping Traffic" at the link above.

RE: #2
Snort will log to `/var/log/alert` (or similar, see snort config) to notify about what it is detecting.

RE: #3
There [are ways](https://serverfault.com/questions/651888/how-can-i-run-a-shell-script-on-a-snort-alert#652158) to run a script on an alert but you need to plan on your script being called 1000s of times a second if snort is triggering on a bursty flood of traffic.

RE: #4
Not sure. Would need more info